Upper bound for $f(x) := e^{-\delta x^2 }\frac{\sinh\left(\sqrt{\delta^2 x^4 -x^2}\right)}{\sqrt{\delta^2 x^4 -x^2}}$
Let $\delta >0$ and consider $j\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\delta 2^j >\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}.$ I am looking for an upper bound of
$$f(x) := e^{-\delta x^2 }\frac{\sinh\left(\sqrt{\delta^2 x^4 -x^2}\right)}{\sqrt{\delta^2 x^4 -x^2}}$$
on the interval $\left[2^{j-1}, 2^{j+1}\right]$ of the form
$$f(x) \leq g(\delta) 2^{-2j}$$
such that $\lim_{\delta \to 0}g(\delta) = 0.$
Thank you for any hint.

I think you should modify some data. You need $\delta x\ge 1$ as otherwise $\delta^2x^4-x^2<0.$ Thus we should have $\delta 2^{j-1}\ge 1,$ i.e. $\delta 2^j\ge 2. $

The function is well defined even if $\delta^2 x^4 -x^2 <0.$ It is simply $e^{-\delta x^2}sinc(\sqrt{x^2- \delta^2 x^4 })!$ then

Ok. Got it. The problem looks interesting.

if a function $g(x)$ has some mild properties and  $\hat{g}(w)$ it is Fourier Transform, you have the upper bound $$|g(x)| \leq \int |\hat{g}(w)|, dw$$ (check this wiki noting that you could use $\hat{f}(\xi) \equiv g(x)$), Have you tried this?

I don't think this could work. The upper bound is not considered on the whole real axis! On the other hand, I don't see any explicit known formula for $\hat f(\xi)$

As pointed out by A. PI, my first answer (supposed to show that no such bound exists for the smallest possible $j$) contained a typo which led to incorrect estimates. This new answer corrects this typo and shows that such an upper bound does indeed exist: we shall show that when $x \ge [2^{j-1}, 2^{j+1}]$, if $\delta \le 1$, then $f(x) \le D_m \delta^m 2^{-2j}$ for all integers $m \ge 1$ and some constants $D_m$.
Fact: For all natural integer $n \ge 1$, for all $u \ge 0$, $u^n e^{-u} \le C_n$ for some $C_n > 0$.
We restrict attention to $\delta \le 1$. We consider three regimes:
(1) If $\delta x \le 1$, then
\begin{align}
f(x) &= e^{-\delta x^2} \mathrm{sinc}(x \sqrt{1 - (\delta x)^2}) \le e^{-(\delta x)^2/\delta} \, .
\end{align}
Moreover, since $x \in [2^{j-1}, 2^{j+1}]$ with $\delta 2^j > \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$, we have $(\delta x)^2 > \frac{1}{32}$, hence taking some integer $n \ge 3$,
\begin{align}
f(x) &\le e^{-1/32\delta} \le C_n 32^n \delta^n = C_n 32^n \delta^{n-2} \frac{(\delta x)^2}{x^2} \\
&\le C_n 32^n \delta^{n-2} \frac{1}{2^{2j-2}} = 4C_n 32^n \delta^{n-2} 2^{-2j} .
\end{align}
(2) If $1 \le \delta x \le a(\delta) := \sqrt{\frac{1 + \sqrt{1 + 4\delta^2}}{2}}$, then $\sqrt{\delta^2 x^4 - x^2} \in [0, 1]$, so
\begin{align}
f(x) &= e^{-\delta x^2} \frac{\mathrm{sinh}(\sqrt{\delta^2 x^4 - x^2})}{\sqrt{\delta^2 x^4 - x^2}} \le 2 e^{-\delta x^2} \, . 
\end{align}
Since $\delta \le 1$, $\delta x \le a(1)$ and so for $n \ge 3$,
\begin{align}
f(x) &\le 2 e^{-(\delta x)^2/\delta} \le 2 e^{-1/\delta}\\
&\le 2 C_n \, \delta^n  = 2C_n \delta^{n-2} \frac{(\delta x)^2}{x^2} \le 8C_n a(1)^2 \delta^{n-2} 2^{-2j} .
\end{align}
(3) If $\delta x \ge a(\delta)$, then
\begin{align}
f(x) &=  \frac{e^{-(\delta x^2-\sqrt{\delta^2 x^4 - x^2})}}{\sqrt{\delta^2 x^4 - x^2}} e^{-\sqrt{\delta^2 x^4 - x^2}} \mathrm{sinh}(\sqrt{\delta^2 x^4 - x^2}) \\
&\le \frac{1}{2} \frac{e^{-\frac{(\delta x)^2}{\delta}( 1 -\sqrt{1 - 1/(\delta x)^2})}}{\delta x^2 \sqrt{1 - 1/(\delta x)^2}} \le \frac{1}{2} \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2\delta}}}{\delta x^2 \sqrt{1 - 1/(a(\delta))^2}} \, . 
\end{align}
Since $1 - 1/(a(\delta))^2 = \frac{\sqrt{1+4\delta^2}-1}{\sqrt{1+4\delta^2}+1} \ge \frac{3}{4} \frac{\delta^2}{1+\delta^2}$, we get
\begin{align}
f(x) & \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2\delta}}\sqrt{1+\delta^2}}{\delta^2 x^2} \, . 
\end{align}
Since $\delta \le 1$, this yields for $n \ge 3$
\begin{align}
f(x) & \le \frac{4 \sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}} \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2\delta}}}{\delta^2 2^{2j}} \le \frac{2^{n+2} \sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}} C_n \delta^{n-2} 2^{-2j}  \, . 
\end{align}
EDIT: What about $\delta \ge 1$? For $m \ge 1$ and $2^{j-1} \le x \le 2^{j+1}$, we also have $f(x) \le D_m \delta^m 2^{-2j}$ (for some possibly larger constants $D_m$).
Case (1): Holds verbatim.
Case (2): Then for any $n \ge 0$,
\begin{align}
f(x) & \le 2 e^{-\delta x^2} \le 2 e^{- x^2} \le 2C_1 x^{-2} \le 8C_1 2^{-2j} \le 8C_1 \delta^n 2^{-2j}\, . 
\end{align}
Case (3): Then for any $n \ge -1$
\begin{align}
f(x) &\le \frac{1}{2} \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2\delta}}}{\delta x^2 \sqrt{1 - 1/(a(\delta))^2}} \le \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{\delta x^2 \sqrt{1 - 1/(a(1))^2}} \\
&\le \frac{2}{\sqrt{1 - 1/(a(1))^2}} \frac{1}{\delta} 2^{-2j} \le \frac{2}{\sqrt{1 - 1/(a(1))^2}} \delta^n 2^{-2j} \, . 
\end{align}

Am I missing something or is it a typo when you write $e^{-\delta_k x^2} = e^{-(\delta_k x)^2/x}$? You might mean $e^{-\delta_k x^2} = e^{-(\delta_k x)^2/\delta_k}.$ In this case the estimate in the 6th line is not true, is  it ?

I would say that if such $g$ exists, then we have $$g(\delta) \leq C_1 \frac{e^{-C_2/\delta}}{\delta}$$
where $C_1, C_2>0$ are independent of $\delta.$

@A.PI You are absolutely right! Then your question admits a positive solution; see my new answer (hopefully free of mistake this time!).

Thank you for your answer and the effort made for it. I guess this also works for any $\delta >0.$

@A.PI I added the cases $\delta \ge 1$ to my answer.

Thank you. sounds perfect now.
